# how to change the name of an unreal engine c++ project

Tags: unreal-engine4

Ive been working on a project for a while now and getting ready to try and share it with a few friends for feedback. however i have changed the name of my game a few times during developing. I have managed to change the project name. but when i export the game it still uses the old name. and when opening the game with steamVR it says elfbow win64 shipping... elfbow is the old name and i guess the win64 is from my export settings

its a blueprint and c++ project

How do i change the name properly?
or do i need to start a brand new project and port it all over?

I have tried creating a new project using the correct name and moving all blueprints and c++ over. changed the .h files from old api to new now but now the blueprints that has a c++ parent is now without parent!

Comment: Have you tried reading through [this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/content-creation/68311-changing-project-name) forum post?

Comment: @Zera I havent seen that post before. but ive followed this one https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/242407/renaming-a-c-project.html

just tried again all blueprints that are child of a c++ just broke now having no parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Open Unreal Engine Launcher**

Open up "Unreal Engine Launcher" and navigate to your list of projects:

2. **Go To Storage Location of a Project**

Right click on the project thumbnail you want to change the name of and choose Show in Folder:

This will open the location where this project is stored.

3. **Change .uproject File Name**

In this folder change the name of .uproject file to the name you want:

Make sure this name is less than 20 characters.

4. **Change Default Engine Config Entry**

Then in the "Config" folder inside the same project folder, open the "DefaultEngine.ini"

Change Project Name under:

"[URL]
GameName=ProjectName"

If you do not see this text: "[URL] GameName=ProjectName", then add it in manually.

5. **Change Folder Name**

Finally, change the name of the project folder to another name. This is not required but it helps to keep everything the same name.

The project will not show up in the Library > My Project section due to changed folder name. Follow this tutorial, starting with Step 3 to associate your project and point Unreal Engine Launcher to the correct path directory

Here is the **link with images**:
https://www.worldofleveldesign.com/categories/ue4/ue4-renaming-your-project.php